# XSockets.Plugin.Framework error

Tags: video, model-view-controller

I've been trying to get teh video cams working my project but without avail, it works fine on a empty made project but when i use it on mine it just doesnt work, doesnt even "start" the project itself without crashing...

```
Tipo de excepção 'XSockets.Plugin.Framework.Exceptions.ExportException' accionado.

Descrição: Exceção não processada ao executar o pedido Web atual. Consulte o rastreio da pilha para obter mais informações sobre o erro e o respetivo ponto de origem no código. 

Detalhes da Exceção: XSockets.Plugin.Framework.Exceptions.ExportException: Tipo de excepção 'XSockets.Plugin.Framework.Exceptions.ExportException' accionado.

Erro de origem: 

Foi gerada uma Exceção não processada durante a execução do pedido Web atual. As informações relativas à origem e localização da Exceção poderão ser identificadas através da utilização do rastreio da pilha de exceções abaixo.

Rastreio da pilha: 


[ExportException: Tipo de excepção 'XSockets.Plugin.Framework.Exceptions.ExportException' accionado.]
   XSockets.Plugin.Framework.Composable.SatifyImportsExports() +237
   XSockets.Plugin.Framework.Composable.Initialize() +104
   XSockets.Plugin.Framework.Composable.GetExport() +36
   EzPlanSoft_Master.XSocketsWebBootstrapper1.Start() in c:\Users\kevin\Desktop\10-01-14\EzPlanSoft Master\EzPlanSoft Master\XSocketsWebBootstrapper1.Web.Bootstrapper.cs:17

[InvalidOperationException: O método de inicialização do pré-carregamento da aplicação Start no tipo EzPlanSoft_Master.XSocketsWebBootstrapper1 emitiu uma Exceção com a seguinte mensagem de erro: Tipo de excepção 'XSockets.Plugin.Framework.Exceptions.ExportException' accionado..]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +550
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +132
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath) +90
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +135
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +516

[HttpException (0x80004005): O método de inicialização do pré-carregamento da aplicação Start no tipo EzPlanSoft_Master.XSocketsWebBootstrapper1 emitiu uma Exceção com a seguinte mensagem de erro: Tipo de excepção 'XSockets.Plugin.Framework.Exceptions.ExportException' accionado..]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9874840
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +456
```

Blowing up on this part right at the beginning:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web;
using XSockets.Core.Common.Socket;

[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(EzPlanSoft_Master.XSocketsWebBootstrapper1), "Start")]

namespace EzPlanSoft_Master
{

    //Create class for the server instance
    public static class XSocketsWebBootstrapper1
    {
        private static IXSocketServerContainer wss;

        public static void Start()
        {
              //blows up on this line
               **var container = XSockets.Plugin.Framework.Composable.GetExport<IXSocketServerContainer>();**
                container.StartServers();
                foreach (var server in container.Servers)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Started Server: {0}:{1}", server.ConfigurationSetting.Location,
                                    server.ConfigurationSetting.Port);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Scheme: {0}", server.ConfigurationSetting.Scheme);
                    Debug.WriteLine("SSL/TLS: {0}", server.ConfigurationSetting.IsSecure);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Allowed Connections (0 = infinite): {0}",
                                    server.ConfigurationSetting.NumberOfAllowedConections);
                    Debug.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried searching for a solution but couldn't find anything relevant to my problem :\

Comment: What version of xsockets are you using?

Comment: If im not mistaken its 3.0, but why would that make a diference when in a newly made project works fine and work project doesnt?

Comment: My guess is that you have an assembly X that depends on assembly Y, but only X is in the bin folder. It is probably easy to fix if you know what assembly is missing.. Contact the XSockets guys, Im sure they will help you out.